# Code works on one computer and compiles (without warning and compiler errors) on another machine but has runtime error

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I've written a program in FORTRAN, it's a simple multiplication program. It seems to work fine on one computer (compiles without warnings and output is correct), but when I scp the folder to another computer, it compiles fine without warnings however, the output changes to a random number, not sure why this is? There's two outputs, one is the algorithm in recursion and the other is done iteratively. Recursion works fine but iterative gives the error. I've run make clean, and I've also tried to change the folder into a new clean folder, still same issue.

Version of the one it works fine on: GNU Fortran (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

Version of the one with wrong output: GNU Fortran (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5

```
program multiplication

    integer(kind = 8) :: multiplier, multiplicand, rcursvmultply, itratvmultply

    write(*,*) "multiplier?"
    read(*,*) multiplier

    write(*,*) "multiplicand?"
    read(*,*) multiplicand

    write(*,*) rcursvmultply(multiplier, multiplicand)

    write(*,*) itratvmultply(multiplier, multiplicand)
end program

recursive function rcursvmultply(multiplier, multiplicand) result(answer)

    integer(kind = 8), intent(in) :: multiplier, multiplicand
    integer(kind = 8) :: answer

    if (multiplier == 0) then
        answer = 0
    else if (multiplier == 1) then
        answer = multiplicand
    else if ((multiplier > 1) .and. (mod(multiplier, 2) == 0)) then
        answer = rcursvmultply((multiplier/2), (multiplicand*2))
    else if ((multiplier > 1) .and. (mod(multiplier, 2) == 1)) then
        answer = (multiplicand + (rcursvmultply((multiplier/2), (multiplicand*2))))
    end if
end function rcursvmultply

integer(kind = 8) function itratvmultply(multiplier, multiplicand)

    integer(kind = 8) :: multiplier, multiplicand

    do while (multiplier > 0)
        if ((mod(multiplier, 2)) == 1) then
            itratvmultply = (multiplicand + itratvmultply)
        end if
        multiplier = multiplier/2
        multiplicand = multiplicand*2
    end do
end function itratvmultply
```

I also get the following warning on the computer that it's not working on:

```
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 4.6 s in the future
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

For the above warning I've make clean on the original computer and scp after that, it doesn't seem to get rid of it. However, when I make clean it doesn't produce the warning again on that computer. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Why the so lengthy and ugly `integer(kind = 8)` when `integer(li)` with `li` defined somewhere is so much better (and shorter)? (rename `li` to whatever you wish...)

Comment: On gfortran 4.9 use `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and the compiler should complain. Valgrind should complain too.

Comment: You're getting a warning because the system clock on the original machine is ahead of the second machine's. Because makes are cached, you have to do a `make clean` on the second machine, so that the files that `make` generates are timestamped with the second machine's clock.

Having said all that, I don't think that's the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this line in `itratvmultply`

```
   itratvmultply = (multiplicand + itratvmultply)
```

is first executed the result variable (ie `itratvmultply`) is not guaranteed to have any particular value; it has not been explicitly assigned to.  This means that the *rhs* of the assignment is, effectively, junk.

The symptoms you report are entirely explicable if on one computer (using one version of a  compiler and an unknown (to us) set of compilation options) the compiler sets the value to `0` whereas on another computer (different compiler version, possibly different options) no such value is provided and the variable gets whatever the bits and bytes just happen to be.

You perhaps think that the compiler sets variables to `0` when the program starts.  That is not guaranteed by the Fortran language standard.  And it's common that compilers at low levels of optimisation set variables to `0` on program start up, but at higher levels do not.

To fix this include the line

```
 itratvmultply = 0
```

in your code prior to the first time the variable appears on the *rhs* of an assignment.  And check your compiler's documentation to find out how to get it to warn you of the use of uninitialised variables.

And @TriskalJM's comment answers your question about the funny futurism in the make process.